# Migrating from Model-First to Code-First: ComplexTypes using EF 5.x DbContext Fluent Generator

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I'm using the latest EntityFramework 5 from NuGet. I don't know if I'm doing wrong, but it seems that complex types don't work with this template! (???) No matter what I do, I always get this compile-time error:

**Running transformation: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ComplexType' to type 'System.Data.Metadata.Edm.PrimitiveType'.**

For example:

1. I created an empty model "SimpleModel", then I added a simple entity in it, "Foo" and a complex property called "Something" of complex type "Bundle". Did all this using the EDM designer.
2. I went to "Generate Database from Model" so as to persist the model in a SQLEXPRESS DB. Ran the script and everything went OK. I tested writing some stuff using the new entity model and it worked fine, i.e., SaveChanges() worked OK.
3. I went to "Add Code Generation Item" and selected this template: *EF 5.x DbContext Fluent Generator* to create the "SimpleModel.tt" series of template files and I immediately got the error above.

When looking at the "SimpleModel.Mapping.cs" file generated by the "SimpleModel.Mapping.tt" template, I see that this code file is incomplete. This is the the only file incomplete, i.e., the generation of mapping code is breaking. Is this template compatible with the latest EF 5?

I have an existing DB with several tables and an entity model in place based on `ObjectContext` and `EntityObjects` (i.e, Model-First stuff). Most importantly, I have an existing data layer that makes use of entities mapped to these tables and lots of the data is rather appropriately bundled in complex types (bundled numeric and text stuff with no identity).

**The point is that I need to migrate my entity model from using `ObjectContext` and `EntityObjects` to `DbContext` and `POCOs`, then I want to go Code-First.** How should I do this?

Any help is appreciated beforehand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should I do this?

Imho either use [EF Power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) (but I think they don't support EF 5 yet) and reverse engineer database or write code first mapping yourselves.

That generator is not provided by MS and if you have any problem with it you should report it to its developer as a bug. If you check [Q/A for this generator in Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d663b99-ed3b-481d-b7bc-b947d2457e3c) it claims that complex types are not supported.

Comment: Yes sir, I see that the best way to go to Code First and generate code to be "owned" is to use the EF power tools and reverse engineer. The problem is that I have an awful lot entities deriving from other entities, with polymorphic associations and TPT mappings, and well, I'm not that fluent yet.
　
In any case, when reverse engineering the DB to Code First, all "inheritance" is obviously lost (but nicely imported as cascading 1 ↔ 0..1 relationships). Also, all complex properties are by default imported as scalar properties. This is all very annoying.. but probably that's the way it has to be.

Comment: I mean, the EF team must be able to write framework tools that are able to read smart programmers' minds and know exactly how we want to have code automatically generated for us, and minimize all work we have to do, right? :-D (sorry, I'm a bit cynical..)